# Node framework or not for console application

Tags: node.js

I am having a node project which will be having 3 application (one web application , 2 console application). 
Web application have only one URL and don't have any view. It just return 200 or 500. 
My current directory structure look like:

```
.
└── src
    ├── modules (common modules used by all app)
    │   ├── aws-dynamodb
    │   │   ├── lib
    │   │   └── test
    ├── config (contains json configuration files)
    └── lib
        ├── app1
        └── app2
```

Small overview of applications:
application interact with mysql and dynamoDB and perform some application logic.

My questions are:

1. Is this directory structure correct? Do you have any suggestion to improve this?
2. Will using any framework will help? I think framework like expressjs or any other are good for web application. Will using any framework (if any please mention which one) will help here for minimizing development time, improve code readability and etc?
3. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go with three different apps, since you will be using node you can write them as modules and `require` where needed. Using this approach for example helps you separate concerns and identify problems more quickly. For more on that: http://blog.izs.me/post/48281998870/unix-philosophy-and-node-js

For sure using other modules will hel you a lot in terms of quick development and you will not have to solve already solved problems.

For the webapp I would suggest [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) as you said, it's really simple to setup and use, for the two console applications have a look at [substack's option parsing module](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist)

Comment: about express as I already told my app doesn't have any view. I don't think I require this. Do you still think any benefit of expressjs for app having only one end point?

Comment: Yeah sure, expressjs will help you even if you don't serve any view, you can just expose the url you want in 5 loc and be done with it.

Comment: if you just have the one endpoint and ur not afraid to write res.writeHead then using connect would be fine as well if that is what ur driving at.

Comment: Of course but adding express is not an overhead and will lead you to a cleaner implementation, also if there will be additions in the future.